# Electron-updater cannot find module 'fs/promises'

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-forge, electron-updater

I have a problem that electron-updater cannot find module 'fs/promises'. All another solutions don`t help me. Here is my log.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'fs/promises'
Require stack:
- E:\VSProjects\Launcher_JS\node_modules\electron-updater\out\AppUpdater.js
- E:\VSProjects\Launcher_JS\node_modules\electron-updater\out\main.js
- E:\VSProjects\Launcher_JS\src\index.js
- E:\VSProjects\Launcher_JS\node_modules\electron-prebuilt-compile\lib\es6-init.js
- E:\VSProjects\Launcher_JS\node_modules\electron-prebuilt-compile\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js
-
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:798:15)
    at Function../lib/common/reset-search-paths.ts.Module._resolveFilename (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:7607:16)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:691:27)
    at Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:853:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\VSProjects\Launcher_JS\node_modules\electron-updater\out\AppUpdater.js:8:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968:30)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (E:\VSProjects\Launcher_JS\node_modules\electron-compile\lib\require-hook.js:77:14)
```

`package.json` contains

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@electron/remote": "^2.0.8",
    "electron-compile": "^6.4.4",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "electron-updater": "^4.6.5",
    "fs-extra": "^10.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "sound-play": "^1.1.0",
    "update-electron-app": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^17.0.21",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "electron": "^17.1.2",
    "electron-builder": "^22.14.13",
    "electron-forge": "^5.2.4",
    "electron-prebuilt-compile": "8.2.0",
    "electron-winstaller": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0"
  }
```

Reinstallation of `node_modules` did not help me. Node.js have version 16.14.0

Answer (score 0):

Delete yarn.lock and node_modules and run

> yarn install

again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. May be it beause I use npm. If I use `const {autoUpdater} = require('electron');` all is fine, but `const { autoUpdater } = require('electron-updater');` does not work. So I need ```const { autoUpdater } = require('electron-updater');` for `autoUpdater.checkForUpdatesAndNotify();`